Why do I keep getting typeError must be integer?
      import csv
      import os

      main_csv = os.path.join("..","Pypoll", "Resources", "election_data.csv")
      dataFile = os.path.join("BallotAnalysis.txt")

      totalBallots = 0
      candidates = []
      ballots = []

      with open(main_csv) as csvFile:
           csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=",")
           csvHeader = next(csvFile)


      for row in csvReader:
           totalBallots += 1

           if row[2] not in candidates:
                 candidates.append(row[2])

                 ballots[row[2]] = 1
           else:
                 ballots[row[2]] += 1

       voteOutput = ""            
       for ballots in candidates:
            votes = candidates.get(ballots) 
            votePCT = (float(votes) / float(totalBallots)) * 100.00

       voteOutput += f"\t{candidates}: {votePCT:.2f}% \n"
       print(voteOutput)

       data = (

            f"\nElection Results\n"
            f"_____________________________________\n"
            f"\tTotal Votes: {totalBallots}\n"
            f"\t        \n"
        )

       print(data)
       with open(dataFile, "w") as textFile:
       textFile.write(data)

I'm trying to get the votes for all 3 candidates but keep running into an error saying:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
its on line 22 but my guess it'll be on all those ballots[row[2]] = 1. What do I need to fix to get the output I desire?

Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

"What do I need to fix to get the output I desire?" Can you explain what you desire? We can't read your mind.

You have to change line ballots = [] to ballots = {} to fix it. But you will get another error at candidates.get(ballots). candidates is a list it doesn't have a get method

and also line  voteOutput += f"\t{candidates}: {votePCT:.2f}% \n"  doesn't make sense. candidates is a list and votePCT will be a last val from loop (that is not going to work as above)


TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

You use ballots as a list type, and to set a new variable in 'ballots' you need use integers. For example, ballots[1] = 1
      ballots = []

      with open(main_csv) as csvFile:
           ...

      for row in csvReader:
           ...
                 ballots[row[2]] = 1
           else:
                 ballots[row[2]] += 1
      ...

In this case, you can cast row[2] to integer(if you sure what the variable is):
ballots[int(row[2])] = 1

